# How to parse both the code and JSDoc comments

Tags: javascript, typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, jsdoc, documentation-generation

In order to create a documentation for a big shared project, I need to parse a JavaScript source code with an output in the JSON format (that will be transformed in other steps). My source code is already commented in the JSDoc format, which provide useful descriptions. Therefore an important requirement of mine is to parse both the code and the comments.

According to my research, there appear to be many different "*AST parsers*" doing what I'm looking for related to code parsing (JSON output), but only a very limited number of them seem to include the documentation along with it. The only popular and maintained one that appears to do it is the typescript parser ( https://astexplorer.net/ ).

I have no experience with typescript, and I might be missing other tools or approach more prone to do what I am looking for, therefore I turn to stack-overflow;

Is there any other specialized tool that can parse both my JavaScript code and JSDoc comments that you would recommend over the typescript parser? Would you recommend a different approach on the subject ?